# "Касаться" и "коснуться".

Tags: орфография

Здесь, я думаю, чередующиеся гласные "о" и "а". Права ли я? Поправьте, если ошибаюсь и объясните, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1):

Касаться - коснуться, чередование гласных в корне КАС(А)/КОС(Н). Выбор гласной А в этом случае определяется по наличию суффикса А, а О в корне пишется перед Н (касательная, прикосновение).

Суффикс А - это формальный признак, в действительности по суффиксу отличают глагол несовершенного вида от глагола совершенного вида с суффиксом НУ.

По наличию суффикса А делается выбор А/О для корней ЛАГ(А)/ЛОЖ, а также написание И/Е для ряда корней (собирать - собрать - соберу, замирать - замереть и др.)